# Increase cookie limit in Apache HTTP Server from 4KB to 8KB/12KB

Tags: apache, http, cookies

I have a Apache HTTP Server which is part of a packaged solution, while handling requests, its failing if request has Cookies greater than 4KB

Is there a setting in httpd.conf I can increase to handle higher limits

Comment: `LimitRequestFieldSize` should do (although default value seems to already be 8190).

Comment: How to verify if LimitRequestFieldSize setting (after updating) which is replaced works or not!?

Comment: Create `COOKIETEXT=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 10000 | head -n 1)`, then send `curl -H "Cookie: $COOKIETEXT" example.com/phpinfo.php`. With default settings, you should get error `400`

Comment: It failed, looks like it never went through

Comment: I have just tested, and after setting `LimitRequestFieldSize 11000` and restarting apache, the above `curl` request works fine

Comment: @DusanBajic The Curl is passing for http : // example.server.com and failing for https : // example.server.com , looks strange

Comment: Maybe you put the `Limit...` directive in :80 VirtualHost? (it should be in main configuration file httpd.conf) (I have tested and for me it behaves the same for http and https)

Comment: I am testing in dev, prod; for one of the server, I do not see any reply to curl

Comment: Do you see any reply without `-H "Cookie: $COOKIETEXT"`?

Comment: There is an auth server which is redirecting, I dumped the headers, still investigating, will keep you updated